# C# DataBound DataGridView with extra column - changes in this column are lost upon sort?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, bindingsource, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I use a DataGridView which is data-bound over a binding source. Additionally I create one CheckBoxCol on the very left for the user. Checking boxes in there and then re-sorting makes all checks disappear. Has anyone an idea how to avoid that?

Here's some code so we're on the same page ;):

```
    dtZg_Betr = new DataTable(); // DataTable object
    // [...] SQL SELECT and so on, I cut that stuff a bit
    adapter.Fill(dtZg_Betr); // OleDbAdapter -> fill the table with the SQL SELECT results
    // [...]
    bsZg_Betrn = new BindingSource(); // BindingSource object
    bsZg_Betrn.DataSource = dtZg_Betr;
    dgvZg_Betr.DataSource = bsZg_Betr; // bind data to DataGridView
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dgvCheckBox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    dgvZg_Betr.Columns.Insert(0, (DataGridViewColumn)dgvCheckBox); // add additional checkbox column


    // Later on somewhere else:
    adapter.Update(dtZg_Betr); // OleDbAdapter -> update DB with table's changes
```

The DataGridView has no further code as such to get filled, later on of course checkbox clicks and such are handled but that should not be relevant for the issue.

Kinds regards!

Comment: show your grid view source code which you have done

Comment: Hey man, I added a few more lines and comments as I quickly copied them over yesterday and didn't see that they were not really sufficient, sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an extra column in `dtResult` to store whether that item has been checked or not. Data controls only keep information about their items between posts if that information can be stored in the data source.

Comment: @Ashok ask Ray for that, not me.

Comment: Problem is (what I didnt mention before - my bad) that I fill this table with an OleDbAdapter's SQL query result. Hence thats not possible, later on I also wanna update the db with that table again. I could add another column to the table and store a bool in there, but that would screw up the entire GetChanges() method of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Renan's hint about that extra column, here is what I did:

I guess I've come up with a good solution:

After filling the DataTable, you add a bool column manually:

```
// [...]
adapter.Fill(dtZg_Betr);
bsZg_Betrn = new BindingSource(); // BindingSource object
bsZg_Betrn.DataSource = dtZg_Betr;
dgvZg_Betr.DataSource = bsZg_Betr; // bind data to DataGridView
```

This will not affect the "RowsChanged" event and as it's an added column, before doing

```
adapter.Update(dtZg_Betr);
```

you can simply delete/remove it again (shouldn't make any difference as added columns do not affect any ChangesEvent when being deleted either)

```
dtZg_Betr.Columns[0].Remove(); // or Columns.Delete(...)
```